# WebAPI creating duplicates of children when doing POST

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm encountering some problems when trying to use a POST with my web api. 
When I'm creating a new `Parent` and want to attach an already existing `Child` I end up with the `Parent` and a newly created instance of `Child` attached instead of the one I wanted attached. I hope it's clear enough or I'll explain better.

I'm using a codefirst EEF web api 2 setup which is very basic and an AngularJs frontend.

I should add that I'm fairly new with both web api and angularJS

These are my two models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Children> Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the angular function that adds calls the web api:

```
$scope.AddParent = function () {
    if ($scope.Name != null) {
        var parentData = {
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Children: $scope.childrenToAdd
        }
        console.log(parentData);
        $http.post("/api/bundles/PostParent", parentData)
            .then(function (data) {
            $location.path("/index");
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
```

And the POST in the web api controller, just the default scaffolded one.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Parent))]
public IHttpActionResult PostParent(Parent parent)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Parent.Add(parent);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = parent.Id }, parent);
}
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307838/entity-framework-adding-existing-child-poco-to-new-parent-poco-creates-new-chi).

Comment: Thank you @Jasen, using the 1st method explained there to just set the state to unchanged solved it perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Jasen in a comment I had a look in this question

[Entity Framework: adding existing child POCO to new Parent POCO, creates new child in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307838/entity-framework-adding-existing-child-poco-to-new-parent-poco-creates-new-chi)

and by using the 1st method explained there I solved the issue.

I added a check to see if the `Children` collection contained any entities if it did I changed their `EntityState`.

This is what I put into my `PostParent()`

```
if (parent.Children.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (Child child in parent.Children)
    {
        db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
```